# Adding tel number field to new acount page "create account" page

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account

Is there a way to add "Tel Number:" input field to create account page in Magento 1.7?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Marius the telephone number field is attached to the address and not the customer. For me the easiest thing to do here would be to add customer address as part of the registration process.

Though this might not fit into your business structure.

This can be achieve by adding the following layout snippet:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
         <action method="setShowAddressFields"><param>true</param></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: Is there a way to only add telephone field in New Customer - Account Information section while admin is creating new customers and as well making it optional field.
I know telephone field is present in New Address section but I am requiring it in Account Information section.

Comment: I am a newbie to magento , Could you please help me with in which file to add this code , my only requirement is to move the Telephone field on Create new account page .

Answer (score 2):

The phone number is an attribute of the customer address object.
If you want it in the register page then you need to create it as a customer attribute.
Adding a customer attribute ... you can find that basically anywhere on the web.
Here are some links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962237/2047249
- http://magentotutorial.org/how-to-add-new-customer-attributes-in-magento/
- http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes