# How to show address fields in register

Tags: customer, ce-1.9.1.0, register, customer-address

I have tried to do it in `register.phtml`, but it did't working for me. I can't find `local.xml` file too.

How i can enable it? This is really important thing in my shop.

Comment: have find this code     <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
 at register.phtml

Comment: i find this but what i should do?

Comment: just remove this  if  coditions if($this->getShowAddressFields()):  code  now it show all address field in form

Comment: @AmitBera I discourage this approach, Reindex'EmAll's answer is a more appropriate approach.

Comment: @Yardi `local.xml` should exist in `app/design/frontend/{PACKAGE_NAME}/{THEME_NAME}/layout/local.xml`. Package name is most likely either "default" or "rwd" depending on your Magento version. The theme name will be unique to your site (something other than "default"). If you have not setup your site to extend the default theme then you should probably read up on that topic before making further changes to Magento's core view scripts.

Answer (score 30):

Create `local.xml` file (if it does not exist already) in `[your_package]/[your_theme]/layout/` folder and add following code:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: Hey, you have an good and awesome xml knowledge.Hats off

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: I agree and voted on this. This is the faster solution.

Comment: Wow, +1 from me, Its worked. Good Thank you

Comment: +1 from me. I thought, this `getShowAddressFields()` is checking some settings in backend, but couldn't find it anywhere. Any idea why it had to be from xml, but not from config?

Answer (score 2):

Step:1

At First From magento admin developer mode on & find the registration  from path as like

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Step:2

Find

```
 <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Just before add following line

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true) ?>
```

Step:Final

This following change as like as below

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true) ?>

<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Comment: I think is better to add that parameter via layout file as described here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25180/23264

Answer (score 0):

Create local.xml file in your theme layout folder and put below code.

```
<customer_account_create> 
<reference name="customer_form_register"> 
  <action method="setShowAddressFields">
  <param>true</param>
</action>
```