# Where to set ShowAddressFields?

Tags: customer-address, register

we need to get the customer address on register page. Where to set the "ShowAddressFields" value?

Comment: you can check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/how-to-show-address-fields-in-register

Comment: local/xml or customer.xml