# setShowAddressFields in custom extension layout doesn't work

Tags: layout, magento-1.9.3.4

I wanted to display customer address fields in register form. I have a custom extension, so I created the layout file in `etc/config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <[myextension]>
                <file>[myextension].xml</file>
            </[myextension]>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

I followed this instruction: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53585/4276 and added the following line in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/[myextension].xml`

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

But the address fields didn't show up. I tried following lines too with no luck:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
            <param>true</param>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.3.4. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I looked into `app/design/frontend/[mypackage]/[mytheme]/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` and the line `if ($this->getShowAddressFields()):` was there.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code locally and it works fine. I can only recommend for you to check is your **[myextension].xml** really working (**by adding/removing block or variable for it**) and check is there another **XML** with setting negative value for `show_address_fields`.

Comment: The xml is loading. I could add a js file to the head. As far as I looked there are no xml or any other file setting the variable (I looked for both `show_address_fields` and `setShowAddressFields`). Do you have any more suggestions?