# Magento 1.9: How to display Telephone on registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, user

Magento version: 1.9
How to add the telephone field into registration form and make it required?

Comment: There are many similar questions, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer-registration-form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go With the following path :

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml**

and comment the if condition from here. :

```
 <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

otherwise get the telephone field outside the if condition.

Comment: Here's better approach http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25180/23264

Answer (score 1):

First, telephone no is Customer address type and it is not customer type attribute.

By default,if you want to enable  telephone then  make  true getShowAddressFields() then 
you need to pull all address fields values  street adress,country ,region,city etc.

Another way, `an customer attribute to Customer  entity type` which will save the telephone to customer table.
Which will show on `customer registration,edit,checkout form`.

See how to
   install an Customer attribute in magento
   [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

There it should no relation between billing/shipping telephone.

Also. need more detail checkout at http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/